# How to intagrate Open Street map editor iD withe geoserver data or planet osm database

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver

I am trying to create my own map with the help of osm data and geoserver,successfully partially completed it with my own SLD..Now I need a web editor for edit that map data .I select "iD" for it. i don't know how to configure it with my planet osm data base

Comment: 1.down load geoserver and deployed it.,2.down load planet OSM data then convert and insert it to database using osm2pgsql ,3.create SLD and preview the map.4. down load iD

Comment: Did you follow the installation steps at https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD?

Comment: I just down load it into my windows system

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind, that your current setup is designed to work for rendering only (so an OSM like basemap).
So what you IMHO need:

1. OSM API services

This is called [rails port](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port) and is a bit tricky, as it's pretty unusal to clone the whole OSM infrastructure for "usual devs". Please be aware that you also need to think about how you want to deal with your and the official data, as you create some 'fork' of the planet and create a parallel world dataset (update workflow, sharealike license, ...)

2. Own iD instance

You should also [host your own iD instance](https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD#installation) (or adapt the JOSM settings for each user) so you can contribute via your own API services from step 1.